# How should i design Users and Friends table when using MongoDB (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am working in a Social Network kind of project, and the suggested database is MongoDB.

I have worked with various projects before and have designed databases in an Relation Database system, but as i am new to NoSQL db (MongoDB). I am stuck with designing stuff.

Consider the below example,

1) The app will have Users and Friends table to hold data of Users and Friends of the users.

Now, is the below design correct?

**users :**

```
_id       username password other_fields
----------------------------------------
2gsyexej2 balan    adsfasf  ..
```

**user_friends :**

```
_id user_id friends
--------------------
1  2gsyexej2 friends
               - 0 
                 - friend_user_id = asdfdf23adfsasdf
               - 1
                  - friend_user_id = efex89sdfsw0dfssf
                        etc.,
```

In above model, i have used "Manual Reference", took the user id from users table
and used it as reference in user_friends table.

is this approach correct? if not please suggest a better approach.

thanks,

Balan

Comment: Read these docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/ They cover these types of issues quite well. If you have a more specific question, I'd suggest you update your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> One user has 30 000 000 friends.

Seriously? The biggest following on the Chinese edition of Twitter, Sina Weibo, where the number of followers per person dwarfs both Facebook and Twitter combined is like 20 million for a single person. That is however rare.

That being said, housing the friend relationship within the root document as the docs ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/ ) and @jorscas suggests would not be wise at all.

I can easily imagine the document growing at a consistently fast rate as a user spends more time on the site accessing more friend relaitonships. This would be bad for a couple of reasons, one for fragmentation of space within MongoDBs extents and two because fast growing documents will probably need moving on the disk, which in itself is a slow and intensive operation. There are more reasons but that's enough.

You have also got to consider the 16meg limit, even 8,000 connections would reach that limit.

So already I would say not to embed. You know the way you would design this in a relational model? I would do that, denormalising when needed while normalising the relationship between users.

Comment: so i should be storing values in a model like `user_id friend_id` and add individual row for each friend relation just like what we do in Relational database in MongoDB?

Comment: @balanv Indeed, this seems too big a relation (and probably querying on that front) to slap into a embedded doc

Comment: but if i do so, then i could not have the full advantage of NoSQl.
and the data will still be stored like in Relational Data model.. no other solution for this?

Comment: @balanv Taking "full" advantage of NoSQL is not all about embedding, it is about the queries you do and embedding only helps if your data fits the structure of embedding, in this case it does not. I would say that a normalised relationship between users is the best and only real solution that doesn't require a lot of work

Answer (score 1):

To represent the relations between users in mongodb the most natural way would be to use [references](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/#manual-references) within a single user's collection in the following way:

```
{
 _id: ObjectId("5099803df3f4948bd2f98391"),
 username: "balan",
 password: "adsafs",
 ...
 other fields
 ...
 friends: [ ObjectId("5099803df3f4948bd2f2334445"), ..., ... ],
}
```

Given the case when the number of friends is huge and `sharding` is needed then the previous structure could make difficult to find a suitable `shard key`.  In that case, I would use a separate friend-pairs collection:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("..."),
  user_id: ObjectId("..."),
  friend_id: ObjectId("...")
}
```

Comment: One user has 30 000 000 friends. What kind of partitioning will be the best ?

Comment: yep, users -> web page , friends -> page view(ip,time,unique cookie val) I have some solution based on MySql (db size now is 20TB).

Comment: What shard do you suggest ? What will happen if you choose user_id ? What happen if you choose user_id ? You  will have 30 000 000 entries in one shard or user will not be able to list friends from all shards. Some unnatural key?

Comment: I think that the useful shard key would be friend_id in this case. If you shard by user_id you would end up having all 30M friends in one shard which wouldn't be useful.

Comment: @iddqd You would only get a users info per shard if that shard can support it (and you have set it up to move chunks in that manner), otherwise when you query for a set range of users friends it will do a query to each of the shards it finds under the user_id you have selected and then do a scatter and gather op.